# Deconvolution of timeseries matrix Matlab/R

Tags: matlab, time-series, deconvolution

I have a matrix of N rows of time-series data. There is a specific noise contaminating measurement of the data that I have some information about.

The noise in the data can be modeled as a poisson distribution that blurs signal from a given column in the matrix to adjacent columns. For example, if the original data should be a single peak surrounded by no signal:

```
0    0    0    1    0    0    0
```

The measured signal distributed slightly asymmetrically resulting in something like this:

```
0.001    0.005    0.1    0.5    0.2    0.001    0
```

If I have a good model of how the noise is distributing the data between the columns, how can I use this information to deconvolve the matrix into an approximation of the original signal?

Comment: This is more a theory question so I would recommend that you ask it on [dsp.se] rather, and one you understand the theory (i.e. how to design your deconvolution kernel or something like that), come back and ask here if you get stuck programming it

Comment: Okay, will do that.

Comment: If anyone finds this message, and wants an answer specific to biological data (which is what I was interested in), try https://cibersort.stanford.edu/